# Android Activity got hanged when executing a function via aidl even though the service is in another process Why?

Tags: android

I have included the following in manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".AService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":Adsadas"
    >
```

In my activity, executed bind service and received the binder and executed the service function
  --> `mRemoteService.firstFunc()` -- executed this from Activity

In service

```
 private final IService.Stub mBinder = new IService.Stub() {
         @Override
        public void firstFunc() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG,">>- firstFunc");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"<<- firstFunc");
        }
}
```

While executing firstFunc() from activity the UI got unresponsive for 10 sec even though I had added as seperate process in manifest. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are using AIDL, which is running on your thread. You will need to run it on another thread or to use messenger for communicating with the service.

You can read more about communicating with service in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

If it's only for running a function, consider using Handler or AsyncTask.